# Automate clipboard pasting with AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I'm asking if someone would be able to help me formulate the code needed paste from the clipboard to a textarea (the ID is known) on a webpage using Google Chrome.

It's a simple script with two lines.  I press a key and it pastes to the textarea:

```
$shift:: 
wb.document.getElementById("viewad-contact-message").Value := Clipboard
```

But the above doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What hotkey are you trying to use?  And has the wb object been set prior to the line of code listed in your post?